# Excel displaying duplicate decimal places on any cell formatted as currency

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-8.1, microsoft-office

I am an Office 365 subscriber and Excel runs nearly perfectly for me. Every issue I had with the software, I was able to solve by googling around, except this hair pulling glitch I am having (for a long time actually).

Whenever I try to format any cell containing a number (or NOT containing a number and receiving a number post-formatting) as Currency/Accounting, my cell will display like this:

[image: the cell shown in the image contains the number 100 formatted as United States dollar]

To make it clear, the cell shown in the image contains the number 100 formatted as United States dollar. The cell type becomes Accounting, and if I try to use Currency, the same thing will happen. Even the samples available in Number Format options are displayed like this:

[image: like this].

Parallel to that, I have a ton of weird custom number formats defined that seem incorrect. If I try to delete any of these custom number formats, Excel crashes. This happens **even in Excel safe mode**.

Things I attempted to solve the problem:

- Complete uninstallation and reinstallation of Office multiple times (Both using the built-in installer, Microsoft FixIt tool and third-party uninstallers);
- Searched for registry keys associated with Office and deleted them;
- Switched number formats under Windows;
- Googled everywhere for this problem, found a few mentions of the issue but with zero solution, including a thread on Microsoft's community forums. Tried registering there only to receive an error stating that "This action is not available right now" or something similar;
- Tried changing the default language used by Office;
- Tried to change the decimal separator in Advanced Settings, both using the "System separator" option and specifying a custom separator;
- As mentioned above, tried to use Excel safe mode, and the crashing bug will always persist;
- Tried also installing the 32 bit version of Office instead of the 64 bit version.

In my view this is a very rare problem that few people have faced, might be specific to my system. It doesn't look like the cause is within Office, but rather outside, somewhere in Windows. I have not succeeded in isolating it so far.

I am running Windows 8.1 Pro x64, with English (US) language but with a different language configuration for the keyboard layout. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like corruption.  Try opening the files in another spreadsheet app (LibreOffice is free and compatible if you don't have Google Sheets set up).  If the formatting is messed up there, also, the issue is in the spreadsheets, themselves (and probably Excel because it put it there).  If it looks OK in another spreadsheet app, the issue is just in how Excel is displaying the content.  Is the issue just with an existing collection of spreadsheets or does it happen when you create a new spreadsheet file from scratch?  (cont'd)

Comment: Try creating a new spreadsheet in another app, save the file, and open it in Excel.  See if that has the same problem.

Comment: @fixer1234 The problematic formatting is not just display, it is actually saved to any created worksheets and persists across computers (although it does not affect the value of any cells). But what is causing the problem is not on Excel, as I have thoroughly uninstalled Office multiple times.

Comment: You can run into a situation where the master template or one of the associated files inside the .xlsx archive gets corrupted.  In that case, reinstalling Excel or opening the old file on another computer won't change it.  You can narrow it down by creating new files from scratch on the reinstalled Excel with no old files open or use of old or custom templates, and creating new files from scratch on another computer, or better, another spreadsheet app on another computer.  See how those behave.  If those are OK, you just need to clean up the old corrupted files.  (cont'd)

Comment: But if those exhibit the same problem, there's either something wrong with Excel (possibly even the installation package), or something else is going on with that computer (a bad Excel add-in, conflict with some other software, some odd system configuration perhaps related to languages or locale settings, etc.).

Comment: @fixer1234 I did try searching the templates already. There are no XLTX files in my computer at all. And I have tried deleting all files in the AppData Templates folder, as well. The installation was the direct Microsoft download from the Office  365 website, the online installer, not the standalone installer. The problem must be outside Office as I talked about earlier, but I am clueless.

Comment: @fixer1234 The culprit is something that is enforcing incorrect custom formats to persist. Editing the custom formats in Excel simply immediately reverts them to what they were (incorrect) and attempting to delete any will cause a crash.

Comment: One thing that still isn't clear is whether the problem is limited to old files.  Have you tried creating new spreadsheets from scratch, with no old files open, on the problem computer and also on other computers?

Comment: @fixer1234 No, the problem will happen even in an Excel application that has just opened. Excel is saving the incorrect format to cells in **any** newly created worksheet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82965/discussion-between-serversauce-and-fixer1234).

Comment: "Causing a crash" isn't something that should happen from doing legitimate activities with custom formats, including deleting them.  That's a sign of a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this problem (on a current up-to-date installation of Windows 10). Although the symptom is in Excel, the cause is not.

It looks like you somehow have '.' as both the thousands separator ("digit grouping symbol") and the decimal separator in your regional settings.

To fix this, go to the same screen, and set them to different values - normally in English, the digit grouping symbol would be ',' and the decimal symbol would be '.' - some regional settings have the opposite by default, and changing one without changing the other would give this effect.

[image: Screenshot of where the relevant setting is]

Comment: For context - this answer was posted before I realised that this was an old question that had been bumped to the top of the list by another (subsequently deleted) answer. It still represents my best guess at an answer, but I acknowledge the OP is unlikely to be helped 2 years later!

Comment: Actually my problem was not this one, because I had tried resetting those settings to default, and it didn't change anything. My problem was most likely a rare glitch in Excel or Windows (worth saying I use Windows 8.1, not 10, and Office 2016, not 2019) -- after a long time it suddenly was fixed after some Office/Windows update. Can't say which one fixed it though.

Comment: @ServerSauce good to know your problem was fixed, even if the exact cause remains a mystery. The control panel page does allow me to get exactly what you saw, and changing it back does indeed get it back to normal though, so might be of use to future visitors with identical symptoms (or indeed to anyone wanting to provide a reproducible test case to Microsoft....)